# How to queue up methods to run until a limit is reached

Tags: c++

So I have a bunch of objects (subclasses of a parent class) with various functions each having different names, I might not have the resources to run all of the functions for each object so I want to have them in a priority list to run over time.

The code bellow is I believe forbidden by c++.
I get "C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function"

```
class A;
class Token;

list<Token> tokenList;

class Token{
public:
    A* a; //Could be A or a child of A
    int* function;
};

class A {
public:
    A() {
        Token token = Token();
        token.a = this;
        token.function = &A::hello;
        tokenList.push_back(token);
    }
    int hello(){
            cout << "hello" << endl;
            return 0;
    }
    
};
```

The code bellow should work but doesn't look elegant and also doesn't support subclasses having multiple functions they could pass to the list, is there a better way to do this I am missing?

```
class A;
list<A*> aList;

class A {
public:
    virtual int funct();
};
class B : public A{
public:
    virtual int funct(){
        hello();
        return 0;
    }
    int hello(){
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
int main(){
//remove objects from list and run their functions in a loop until list is empty or max number of functions were run
```

Thanks Ted

Solution: Using the first example as mentioned I changed `int* function;` to `int (A::*function)();`. Then I can run the function with something like this

```
 A tmp = A();
    
    
    Token token = *tokenList.begin();
    A *a = token.a;
    (a->*token.function)();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `int* function;` with `int (A::*function)();` to make it an actual member function pointer?

Comment: Use lambdas to encapsulate whatever operations you require. Then your queue/dispatcher just needs to manage `std::function<void()>` values.

Comment: title doesn't match  up with question text

Comment: @Ted I changed the first code as mentioned to `int (A::*function)();` and that seemed to work but I can't seem to be able to run the method afterwards and I am confused how to call the method. Neither `a.*(fun);` or `a->*(fun);` work where a is a pointer to class A object and fun is `int (A::*fun)();`

Comment: You use the instance of `A` that you want to call the function on. `(a.*token.function)();`

Comment: @Ted `Token token = *tokenList.begin();` `A *a = token.a;` and then I tried what you said `a.*token.function();` I get "error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘token.Token::function (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* token.Token::function) (...)’" and the IDE is giving me `called object type int (A::*)(); is not a function or function pointer`

Nevermind it's `(a->*token.function)();` my bad

Comment: Yeah, if `a` is an `A*`, you need to use `->`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code `int* function;` is a pointer to an integer and not a pointer to a function.

If you would define it as  `int (*function)();` you could easily do what you want.  But it would still not work with member functions.

So you need to define it as a pointer to a member function:  `int (A::*function)();`

Here an example to make it work:

```
class Token{
public:
    A* a; //Could be A or a child of A
    int (A::*function)();  // pointer to member function with no arg, returning int
};

class A {
public:
    A() {
        Token token = Token();
        token.a = this;
        token.function = &A::hello;  // Use the address of member function
        tokenList.push_back(token);
    }
    int hello(){
            cout << "hello (" << this <<")"<< endl; // added the address of a to see for which object
            return 0;
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;
    A b; 
    for (auto& token : tokenList )
        (token.a->*token.function)(); // invoke the member function on the object pointer
}
```

**[Online demo](https://ideone.com/m4KwVE)**

I didn't notice that your tokenList was a global variable.  This is rather risky, as everything you create an A (including a temporary one), the tokenList will be updated.  When you'll execute it, you'll therefore risk of having dangling pointers, i.e. pointing to an `A` instance that has already destroyed.

Comment: the token is a variable of the object and doesn't get destroyed, just a bad example from my part. Now if the object gets destroyed which is a possibility I was thinking of checking whether the pointer to the object is null since I don't want to run the method if the object ends up being destroyed before its method gets executed. Thinking about it, the pointer won't end up being null if the object gets destroyed and I have a new issue to solve..

Comment: I edited the answer, because in my first version I didn't notice that the token list was global.  The token is indeed not the problem:  it gets destroyed at the end of the construction but before it gets copied into the list.  But the problem is the A pointer, unless you make sure that every A is created in the freestone and that you delete them after the invocation via the token list.